# Constraint Ambiguity in Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, constraints

At the very beginning I add scrollView and try to add constraints.
Found [here](https://medium.com/@mufakkharulislamnayem/scrolling-in-a-horizontal-uistackview-with-storyboard-e02a9aab555b) instruction. Do THE SAME, but it doesnt work.

Added:
Align leading 
Align trailing
Height constrain
Align senter Y to Superview

[My xcode scrinshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlktY.png)

It must be enough, isnt it? 
So where is mistake?

Comment: To understand the issue You have to publish the constraints error by clicking on the right red arrow

Comment: I found a decision: I used "Remove constraint at build time" "Because we don’t need this constraint actually, but to make xcode happy to stop showing the error in the document outline."
But many thanks for your answer.